# Оптимизация запросов в БД

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

У меня есть проверка на существование сущностей в БД.

```
 if db_is_team_exist(team_id):
     if db_is_user_exist_by_id(user_id):
         ok
     else:
         raise ObjectDoesNotExist("user", user_id)
 else:
     raise ObjectDoesNotExist("team", team_id)
```

Функции запроса в бд:

```
def db_is_team_exist(team_id: str) -> bool:
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT COUNT(1) FROM teams WHERE id='{team_id}';")
    return bool(cursor.fetchone()[0])

def db_is_user_exist_by_id(user_id: str) -> bool:
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users WHERE id='{user_id}';")
    return bool(cursor.fetchone()[0])
```

Иногда таких проверок становится слишком много, чтобы я мог позволить себе такую нагрузку на БД. Можно ли как-то проверить существование двух+ сущностей, которые лежат в разных таблицах с помощью одного запроса? Или уменьшить кол-во запросов в БД другим способом?

Comment: Что такое "много проверок" - тысяча в секунду? Индексы по полям, которые участвуют в условии, построены? С индексом такой запрос должен мгновенно выполняться. Если тормозит само обращение к БД из питона, то по идее можно кэшировать запросы (хоть через `lru_cache`). Или вообще вытянуть всю таблицу в память и проверять это всё в памяти. Вопрос в том, как часто меняются данные, надо весь сценарий использования видеть, чтобы оптимизировать правильным образом.

Comment: @CrazyElf. Это часть апи кода. Проверки происходят при каждом запросе. Как минимум на проверку существования сущности и пользователя, который отправляет запрос. Так же в некоторых случаях происходит проверка на уровень доступа пользователя. В среднем на указанные в вопросе запросы уходит 0.003991 секунды. Если взять, как в вашем, комментарии 1000, не учитывая ассинхронность, то на их обработку уйдет почти 4 секунды.  Насчёт индексов. Все запросы происходят по PRIMARY KEY, который индексируется автоматически.

Comment: Ну то есть реально может быть такая нагрузка, как 1000 запросов одновременно? Ок. Насчёт асинхронности, кстати, хорошее замечание - может и правда, асинхронность какую-нибудь прикрутить и это поможет? Сами запросы к БД я вижу не тормозят. Вопрос - эти 1000 пользователей могут прийти так, что вы их одним пакетом можете в БД запросить? Если такое возможно, тогда конечно можно сделать запрос в БД, который вернёт в ответ массив со значением 1 или 0 для каждого пользователя. И наверное это будет быстрее. Но я что-то сомневаюсь, что есть такой сценарий.

Comment: Но в любом случае без знания всех параметров системы придумывать что-то сложно. Всего пользователей сколько - миллион, миллиард? Может правда держать в какой-то кэширующей сущности такие данные, чтобы они быстро обрабатывались и не дёргали базу. Но сложно поддерживать кэш в актуальном состоянии.

Comment: @CrazyElf 1000 запросов в сек. - это даже для голого веб-сервера без php/python/sql многовато. А если больше (в 2 и больше раз), то это гайки. При очень большом кол-ве однотипных запросов (userID, itemID) можно тупо хранить их все в ОЗУ в (виде бинарных векторов, например), а проверку наличия делать своим ПО (с\с++). К примеру, ловить http-запрос на проверку на каком-то левом порту, парсить его и смотреть, что в векторах. Скомпиленная программка такого рода будет работать намного-намного быстрее. Вектор обновлять в рантайме (я не думаю, что данные в БД меняются так же часто).

Comment: @Zombotron Ну вот именно, что если речь про веб-сервер, то там именно сам сервер уже может не тянуть. Там другие средства нужно для кэширования запросов применять. Пока автор вопроса нормально не опишет систему можно только гадать, где там узкое место.